i have 200 classes in my project, should i create per each class one interface?
this is actually an issue
so when we create an interface per class in a project
then when someone new join, it is gonna be really hard to keep track on the flow and the integration between classes
for example:
I have 5 classes and each class has an interface, in order to debug something in my application I need to go to first class and then see which interface is using and injecting, and then go to that interface and see which class is implementing the interface?
this is very harder than this scenario:
I have 5 classes none of them has interface, and inject directly the class (instead of the interface)
so now I can find the flow easier.
I am doing this wrong in my project?
should I only use dependency inversion, when it is needed? like connection between 2 teams?

This question is similar to: Java Interfaces Methodology: Should every class implement an interface?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes, debugging might seem harder with interfaces but it's more a symptom of a strongly coupled or poorly tested project. The usage of an interface is based on the concept that one class shouldn't rely on other class implementation details - just on the set of public methods it offers. And implementation shouldn't rely on context that uses it. That approach allows us to treat each class in more isolated way, where unit tests are the primary behavior-inspecting tool, instead of the debugging.
For example:
public class Foo {
  private IBar bar;
  
  public Foo(IBar bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }

  public FooResult DoSomething() {
    BarResult barResult = this.bar.doWhatBarDoes();
    return this.DoSomethingInternal(barResult);
  }

  private FooResult DoSomethingInternal(BarResult barResult) {
    //some behavior
  }
}

interface IBar {
  public BarResult doWhatBarDoes();
}

public class Bar implements IBar {
  public Bar() {
  }

  public BarResult doWhatBarDoes() {
    //some implementation  
  }
}

public class AnotherBar implements IBar {
  public AnotherBar() {
  }

  public BarResult doWhatBarDoes() {
    //some other implementation  
  }
}

Let's say you need to debug the insides of DoSomething() in Foo class. All you know at that point is that it uses one of IBar implementations and to examine that behavior you need to inspect which one was injected.
But the real question is - what's the point of that debugging? In many cases (of course not every case) you either want to inspect how DoSomething() treats the result of this.bar.doWhatBarDoes(); or inspect the execution of this.bar.doWhatBarDoes(); itself.
Inspection of this.bar.doWhatBarDoes(); itself shouldn't be dependent on the external context that calls that method. And inspection of DoSomething() shouldn't be dependent on the details of creating BarResult (so it shouldn't matter which implementation was used). Either the creation of barResult is the problem or the usage of it.
So instead of debugging through the whole process, it might be more useful to extend testcases for unit tests of two isolated functionalities.
So regarding your title question - should you create interface per each class in your project? There is no clear right or wrong answer. Instead of creating (or not creating) interfaces just for the principle of it, focus more on the consequences of doing so. Slightly more complicated debugging is one of the disadvantages, but there are also a lot of advantages. The ability to decide whether (and when) to use the interface will simply come with time and experience.
Try to always think about a class from the perspective of another class that uses it. Does that second class need a whole class or just some subset of its functionalities? Or does the same functionality might be replaced or expanded by a different implementation?
